# Ajax.BeginForm Posts twice in partial view - not unobtrusive X 2

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have seen many posts regarding Ajax.BeginForm posting x2 in a partial view.  Most, if not all answers point to unobtrusive.js being included x2.  I have checked and rechecked and unobtrusive is only included on the page once.  It only shows up once in the Page Source of the rendered page.

My question is...  Are there any OTHER reasons for this behavior of posting twice from a Ajax.BeginForm in a Partial View besides unobtrusive registering x2 in the page ?

Thanks in advance if anyone has ideas....

Comment: what is your question - what sort of error / output are you getting?

Comment: The Ajax.BeginForm is posting twice, not once, so all the logic to running twice...

Comment: @Shell...  I included all the code as I have been banging my head, reviewing, reviewing reviewing... so I thought I'd be complete... in other questions, I am told to put more code... so damn if you do, damn if you don't I guess

Comment: @Dan what i mean that remove unnecessary declarations like Import Namespace, Tags <Header></Header>, So, user can get only essential things. even the code is too large and it is necessary to add in the question then try to make a [pastie](http://pastie.org) for that. So, the original question can be readable properly.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently, this is cause by the Telerik MVC wrappers, and only when running in Debug.  I have been trying The wrappers out with this project.

The solution is to add an ignore to the bundles

bundles.IgnoreList.Ignore("*.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js", OptimizationMode.WhenDisabled);

I added this line at the end of my BundleConfig and the issue went away

Answer (score 0):

I had jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js in the BundleConfig. so when the page load, it gets loaded, and when the partial view loads it loads again. I removed it from BundleConfig and added just to the partial view. that fixed the issue for me.